# Working with nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I am using LINQ and have a few properties thats DateTime? type.

If i now want to add the value from a textbox i cant seem to get this to work.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ScoringLastUpgrade", DbType="Date")]
public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ScoringLastUpgrade
```

The textbox i use i have made sure with javascript that the format will be '2011-06-17'

But now when i try to do this:

```
myObject.ScoringLastUpgrade = Convert.ToDateTime(txtScoringUpgradeDate.Text).ToShortDateString();
```

I get this error: "Cannot convert type string to DateTime?"

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert it to string using 'ToShortDateTimeString', just set the result of `Convert.ToDateTime`:

```
myObject.ScoringLastUpgrade = Convert.ToDateTime(txtScoringUpgradeDate.Text);
```

Assuming you've done sufficient validation on `txtScoringUpgradeDate.Text`?

My preference when dealing with these type conversions is to use the `TryParse` method, e.g.:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtScoringUpgradeDate.Text, out date))
    myObject.ScoringLastUpgrade = date;
```

The `Convert.ToDateTime`, much like the explicit `DateTime.Parse` will throw an `InvalidCastException` when an excepional value occurs. It's better to make your code fault tollerant then needlesly catch an exception.

**UPDATE**: based on your last comment:

You shouldn't return `DateTime.MinValue` in this case, as `MinValue` is less than the supported min value of a `datetime` column. the CLR `DateTime` supports a date range down to 0000-01-01, whereas the SQL `datetime` (as well as the comparative CLR `SqlDateTime` type) supports a minimum value of 1753-01-01. As it as a nullable `DateTime`, you should set it to null:

```
public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(this string date)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    return (DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateTime))
        ? (DateTime?)dateTime
        : null;
}
```

Comment: But what about that the database datatype is date, wont this be a problem?

Comment: `DateTime` is the equivalent CLR datatype in this instance. It wouldn't matter if the database uses `date`, `time` or `datetime` as the Linq to Sql engine will map the appropriate value for you. Also, you're not doing anything different besides how you obtain a valid `DateTime` value for your `DateTime?` property.

Comment: I decided to make it into a ext method so i could use it all over.

    `public static DateTime toDateTime(this TextBox aTextBox)
        {
            DateTime date;
            if (aTextBox.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                if(DateTime.TryParse(aTextBox.Text, out date))
                {
                    return date;
                }
            }
            return System.DateTime.MinValue;
        }`

This should be a correct way to do it right?

Answer (score 3):

The `.ToShortDateString()` call is converting it into a string. You should remove that call.

Also, you say you've made sure of the format with javascript. What if the user doesn't have javascript, you should do server-side checks too. Also, since it's in a given format, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` (so an invalid format doesn't throw an exception) since its more efficient. (The format string would be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`) i believe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have put `ToShortDateString()` at the end there, effectively converting the `DateTime` back to a `string` again. Try removing that part of the line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (.cshtml):

```
<td>@item.InvoiceDate.Value.ToShortDateString().ToString()</td>
```

Where InvoiceDtae is Nullable Date in DB